# Increment heap memory in a container with Kubernetes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, deployment

I'm facing with a issue in my spring boot service. After deploy it on kubernetes I have a Java Heap Space. I have set the next environment configuration on my deployment.yaml:

```
  containers:
    - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
      image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
      imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
      env:
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: "-Xms512M -Xmx512M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1"
```

But after make a new deployment I'm still having the same issue because this way hasn't had effect. I have gone inside of my image and I have seen that the heap memory is around 200MB.

My image is working under openjdk 11. Any idea about why is not working correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you just set that env variable, which does nothing, you need to add it to your RUN/ENTRYPOINT java command in your Dockerfile or as args for your kubernetes command.

Most likely something like

```
ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -jar <path to your jar>
```

would work

Comment: I want to avoid modify my dockerfile, so I would prefer add in my deployment.yaml, I already check the option of add it as args in my deployment.yaml

Comment: @nole, did it work as you expected ?

Comment: hi @mario i have changed my entry point and i still have the same problem maybe the memory is managed by the cluster. I am still investigating.